# PULL Profiles from WordPress Database and Display them on WP Page

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am building a WordPress website where I want profiles to be displayed directly on the Home page from the Database as members add their profiles. What I have so far is this:

If anyone register through the website, their info is stored in a database and their profiles are displayed in a result page. For example: if you use the search form and search for specific member they will display in: http://www.website.com/results/URL (Where results is the page that always display results. Here is the code I have that works just fine:

```
<style>
.person_name {
  font-size:13px; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; padding-top:8px;
}
.person_image {
  padding:4.2px; border:1px solid #aaa; width:125px;
}
</style>

<?php $state=$_GET['state'];
$county=$_GET['county'];
$city=$_GET['city'];
$zip=$_GET['zip'];

/**/
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("user") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE city='".$city."' OR zip='".$zip."' ORDER BY name")
or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<div style='display:inline-block;margin-right:15px;cursor:pointer;' onclick='location=\"http://www.website.com/profile/?id=".str_replace(' ','_',$row["name"])."\"'>";
echo "<div class='person_image'><img src='http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/".$row['photo']."' style='' width='125px' /></div>";
echo "<div class='person_name'>".$row['name']."</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
/**/

//echo "page for: ".$state." ".$county." ".$city." ".$zip;
?>
```

On my home page and where I want the data to be displayed other than the result page is kinda tricky. I want to be able to only display 6 profiles. I also want to mention that I am using the Execute PHP plugin that helped me display the php in pages.

Here is some of my home page code where I want to display those profiles:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'Our Newest Members' ) ) {
            echo '<div class="Our Newest Members">';
            echo '<h4>' . __( 'Our Newest Members', 'themename' ) . '</h4>';
            dynamic_sidebar( 'Our Newest Members' );
            echo '</div><!-- end .OurNewestMembers -->';
        }
```

I am not a code savvy person but always willing to learn and I am also more than happy to answer any follow up questions. Thank you so much for all your help, this community ROCK!!!!

John

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select 'n' amount of rows for any given result set you can always use "Select top N" where N is a number, i'm guessing this is what you want to do. So for T-SQL(SQL Server, MS SQL)

```
SELECT TOP 6 *
```

for MySQL(I'm guessing this is what you would use since it's wordpress)

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE city='".$city."' OR zip='".$zip."' ORDER BY name LIMIT 6
```

Comment: I was looking more for an //include code to use. How will the final code look like to be included in the home page. Thanks a lot for your reply, I appreciate it!